# Prolog: how does variable instantiating work, what is the scope of local variables

Tags: prolog

i'm new to prolog programing, and my first task is to make a quadratic equation solution finder. I have found and rewritten a input/output version of it, however i do not understand the usage of paranthesis. Do they work just as in C/C++? It seems to me as if they should be used every time i introduce a new variable being input by the user. Otherwise i keep getting specific error:
"ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated"
I looked up for a clear explanation of that problem, but haven't found a sufficient answer to my problem.

```
q :- write('A = '),
 read_integer(A),
 (   A = 0, write('Not a quadratic equation');
     write('B = '),
     read_integer(B),
     write('C = '),
     read_integer(C),
     D is B*B-4*A*C,
     (   D = 0, write('x = '), X is -B/2/A, write(X);
         D > 0, write('x1 = '), X1 is (-B+sqrt(D))/2/A, write(X1), nl, write('x2 = '), X2 is (-B-sqrt(D))/2/A, write(X2);
         D < 0, write('Delta < 0!')
     )
 ). q.
```

I do not know why it works only if I keep up paranthesis after reading A, and after making the equation for D value. Does it have something to do with their scope? What is instantiation in prolog then? Just to clarify, here's exactly what i have cut out:

```
q :- write('A = '),
 read(A),
   A = 0, write('Not a quadratic equation');
     write('B = '),
     read(B),
     write('C = '),
     read(C),
     D is B*B-4*A*C, 
        D = 0, write('x = '), X is -B/2/A, write(X);
         D > 0, write('x1 = '), X1 is (-B+sqrt(D))/2/A, write(X1), nl, write('x2 = '), X2 is (-B-sqrt(D))/2/A, write(X2);
       D < 0, write('Delta <0!'), nl, q.
```

Error:

```
A = 1.
B = |: 2.
C = |: 1.

ERROR: is/2: Arguments are not sufficiently instantiated
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Prolog is based on a different paradigm, it's rather obvious that tokens have different meaning. Removing the parenthesis you're changing the scoping of the *disjunction* operator ';'/2. Such operator is syntax sugar meant to simplify alternative branches inside a same clause. By default, clauses are *conjunction* of goals, expressed by the ','/2 operator. Once removed the parenthesis, SWI-Prolog warns about

```
Singleton variable in branch: D
```

Now is clearer what is the problem: the value you 'assigned' (we say to bind, instead of assign) with

```
D is B*B-4*A*C,
```

has been forgotten when the execution has reached the goal `D > 0,`. Arithmetic evaluation, performed by operator '>'/2 on both arguments, requires instantiated variables to numeric values.

Comment: Thank you for that explanation. In this case if i would like to bind any value coming from arithmetic operations to a variable, in order to keep it's value the same as far as i want, i should include everything after my binding in paranthesis? That is, is it a general rule and good prolog programing practice? What i exactly mean is for instance what happens after binding D in the first code block.

Comment: The parenthesis are required to group conjunctions, since ';' has higher precedence than ','. For the case at hand, just be sure you don't change the 'execution flow' though

Comment: as best practice, always move the ';' at **start** of line. It's way too easy to overlook such important change in control flow when it sits at **end** of line. Boris already expressed better this stating that a Prolog compiler should emit a warning for ';' at end of line...